# My Apache is logging even an IPV6 Address as an IPV4 address. How to fix this?

Tags: apache, ipv6

My phone has an IPV6 address. When I hit my apache server, I see an IPV4 address being logged there. I did that with multiple IPV6 address devices and same thing happened. Kindly help what I can do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.